# How to make CDT C parser include preprocessor statements into the AST?

Tags: c, eclipse, parsing, eclipse-cdt

When I parse a C file using CDT's parser, I get an AST, which does not contain preprocessor statements. That is, when I run a `TestASTVisitor` on the AST, it does not find any `IASTPreprocessorStatement`s.

The preprocessor statements are returned by the method `ast.getAllPreprocessorStatements()`.

How can I make the preprocessor statements appear in the AST?

My ultimate goal is to create a piece of software, which

1. converts a file in a certain C-like language into an AST and
2. then can use that AST as a template to generate code parts.

   ```
   @Test
   public void test3() throws CoreException, IOException
   {
   final IASTTranslationUnit ast = createAst();

   final TestASTVisitor visitor = new TestASTVisitor();

   ast.accept(visitor);

   for (final IASTNode curNode : ast.getChildren())
   {
       curNode.accept(visitor);
   }
   }

   public class TestASTVisitor extends ASTVisitor {
   public TestASTVisitor() {
       super(true);

       this.shouldVisitAmbiguousNodes = true;
       this.includeInactiveNodes = true;
       this.shouldVisitImplicitNames = true;
       this.shouldVisitTokens = true;
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTTranslationUnit tu) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(tu);
       return super.visit(tu);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTName name) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(name);
       return super.visit(name);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTDeclaration declaration) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(declaration);
       return super.visit(declaration);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTInitializer initializer) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(initializer);
       return super.visit(initializer);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTParameterDeclaration parameterDeclaration) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(parameterDeclaration);
       return super.visit(parameterDeclaration);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTDeclarator declarator) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(declarator);
       return super.visit(declarator);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTDeclSpecifier declSpec) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(declSpec);
       return super.visit(declSpec);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTArrayModifier arrayModifier) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(arrayModifier);
       return super.visit(arrayModifier);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTPointerOperator ptrOperator) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(ptrOperator);
       return super.visit(ptrOperator);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTAttribute attribute) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(attribute);
       return super.visit(attribute);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTAttributeSpecifier specifier) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(specifier);
       return super.visit(specifier);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTToken token) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(token);
       return super.visit(token);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTExpression expression) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(expression);
       return super.visit(expression);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTStatement statement) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(statement);
       return super.visit(statement);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTTypeId typeId) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(typeId);
       return super.visit(typeId);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTEnumerator enumerator) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(enumerator);
       return super.visit(enumerator);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTProblem problem) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(problem);
       return super.visit(problem);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(ICPPASTBaseSpecifier baseSpecifier) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(baseSpecifier);
       return super.visit(baseSpecifier);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(ICPPASTNamespaceDefinition namespaceDefinition) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(namespaceDefinition);
       return super.visit(namespaceDefinition);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(ICPPASTTemplateParameter templateParameter) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(templateParameter);
       return super.visit(templateParameter);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(ICPPASTCapture capture) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(capture);
       return super.visit(capture);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(ICASTDesignator designator) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(designator);
       return super.visit(designator);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(ICPPASTVirtSpecifier virtSpecifier) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(virtSpecifier);
       return super.visit(virtSpecifier);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(ICPPASTClassVirtSpecifier classVirtSpecifier) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(classVirtSpecifier);
       return super.visit(classVirtSpecifier);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(ICPPASTDecltypeSpecifier decltypeSpecifier) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(decltypeSpecifier);
       return super.visit(decltypeSpecifier);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(IASTComment comment) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(comment);
       return super.visit(comment);
   }

   @Override
   public int visit(ASTAmbiguousNode astAmbiguousNode) {
       printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(astAmbiguousNode);
       return super.visit(astAmbiguousNode);
   }

   private void printMessageIfPreprocessorStatement(Object node)
   {
       if (node instanceof IASTPreprocessorStatement)
       {
           System.out.println("Found preprocessor statement");
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Did you consider customizing a compiler, e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) with your pass for your needs? It probably is better than customizing Eclipse-CDT, because it benefits entirely from the compiler infrastructure....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I need the whole thing to run inside an Eclipse RCP application. If there is a good way to run your option inside Eclipse, please tell me.

Comment: @DP_, it's an old question, but if the problem is still pending I could help. Let me know.

Comment: @STiGMa whether or not the problem is still pending for the OP, I'm sure others (including myself) would appreciate having an answer here.